# Blog design using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP to build a blog (just a personal project, nothing serious) and for the moment I have the next controllers:

- PostsControllers (actions: index, about, archive, show, edit)
- UsersControllers (actions: register, login, logout)

I think that actions like 'index', 'about' and 'archive' should be placed in a different controller (like BlogsController) because they are not actions related to a single post.

I have been searching in the Internet and all I have found is that most people use only a single controller for both blog and post actions (a BlogsController or a PostsController).

So my question: should I have a separated controller for actions like 'index', 'about', 'archive' and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should keep a controller for each discrete entity type (eg, `Post`, `User`, `Comment`). You can then have actions such as `/posts/view/5` to view a blog post of ID `5`. If you want to make the URL reflect the blog-ness, then you can map a route for `/blog/5` or `/blog/posts/5` (see the [CakePHP documentation on routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)).

If you plan on creating a site with more than just a blog, you could also consider creating a blog plugin with CakePHP (again, [see the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html)). Then all your blog-related actions will be confined within a single plugin for organization. Consequently, this also makes it easier to deploy your blogging code for other websites.

Comment: So, is ok that my PostsController has actions like 'about' (about the blog, not about a post) even if 'about' is not a post related action?

Comment: @enrmarc No. Actions should deal only with the entity they refer. If you have actions that are particular to the blog itself, then that would warrant a `BlogController` with no Model (eg, `public $model = array();`). An about page sounds awfully static, however, so that would be best as a page in the `/app/views/pages/` directory as a `about.ctp` file. Then you can create a route for `/pages/about` to something like `/blog/about` if you wish.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my about page is basically static but has a sidebar with the recent posts (I use a element to reuse that view: sidebar.ctp). But sidebar.ctp needs a $posts variable to show the recent posts ... so, I need an `about` action in BlogsController, right?

Comment: That's one way to do it. I haven't used Cake in a couple years so you're starting to hit rusty parts of my memory, but I think you want a helper and/or component that can feed the data for the layout (from your `AppController`). That way any page that uses the `sidebar.ctp` element will get the list of posts sent to it. Then you're safe to easily use static pages all you want once its set up. This will keep the concerns of your sidebar isolated from the logic of the rest of your application.

Comment: @enrmarc Note, they're literally called `Helper` and `Component` in Cake. Consult the documentation as always.

Comment: -1: having separate controller for each domain entity implies that presentation is tightly coupled to model layer. **This is the worst thing one could do.**.

Comment: @tereško This is exactly the design that CakePHP encourages, so if you feel it's the worst thing you could do, then find a new framework. I never mentioned anything here about presentation logic being coupled to the controllers. The controllers are particular to their models so that they can gather the data as needed, the presentation is then built from using the API exposed by the controllers. What you're proposing would create greater coupling between the views and controllers because you're building your controllers around how the view of your application is structured.